# Rails sass import css file is not working on staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a .css file in

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets/myfile.min.css
```

I am trying to refer to that file from my main.css.scss file

```
@import 'myfile.min.css';
```

This works on localhost but not on staging.
On my application.rb I have

```
config.sass.load_paths << Rails.root.join("vendor","assets","stylesheets");
```

But the file is not been found on staging.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can't import regular CSS files with Ruby's SASS implementation. I follow Node's SASS implementation more closely, and they [just recently tried to disable this functionality](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2362) stating it doesn't align with the SASS spec.

You should look into Rails' [asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). You would add something like this to the top of your `main.css.scss`

```
//= require myfile.min
```

This puts the import burden on Sprockets, leaving SASS to do it's own thing afterward.